# How to access Grails configuration in Grails 2.0?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I have obtained the latest Grails 2.0 milestone, and I am seeing a deprecation warning for the `ConfigurationHolder` class:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
```

The deprecation message simply says "Use dependency injection instead" which is not very helpful to me. I understand dependency injection, but how can I wire up a bean with the proper Grails configuration so I can access it at runtime?  I need to access the configuration from places other than my Controllers and Tags (such as `BootStrap`).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

- If you need it in an artifact that supports dependency injection, simply inject `grailsApplication`

  ```
  class MyController {
      def grailsApplication

      def myAction = {
          def bar = grailsApplication.config.my.property
      }
  }
  ```
- If you need it in a bean in, say, `src/groovy` or `src/java`, wire it up using `conf/spring/resources.groovy`

  ```
  // src/groovy/com/example/MyBean.groovy
  class MyBean {
      def grailsApplication

      def foo() {
          def bar = grailsApplication.config.my.property
      }
  }

  // resources.groovy
  beans = {
      myBean(com.example.MyBean) {
          grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
          // or use 'autowire'
      }
  }
  ```
- Anywhere else, it's probably easiest to either pass the configuration object to the class that needs it, or pass the specific properties that are needed.

  ```
  // src/groovy/com/example/NotABean.groovy
  class NotABean {
      def foo(def bar) {
         ...
      }
  }

  // called from a DI-supporting artifact
  class MyController {
      def grailsApplication
      def myAction = {
          def f = new NotABean()
          f.foo(grailsApplication.config.my.property)
      }
  }
  ```

**Update:**

[Burt Beckwith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160313/burt-beckwith) recently wrote a couple of blog posts on this. [One discusses using](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=993) `getDomainClass()` from within domain classes, while the other offers the option of [creating your own holder class](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1017) (if none of the solutions above are appropriate).

Answer (score 59):

An alternative to grailsApplication is the [Holders](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/util/Holders.html) class,

```
import grails.util.Holders

def config = Holders.config
```

You get config directly off of Holders, no injection needed, which is nice for utility classes, etc.

Comment: This is probably the most straightforward way, since there's a direct 1:1 mapping to the deprecated class.

Comment: When is `grails.util.Holders` preferable to injecting `grailsApplication`?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel when you don't want to have Spring control the lifecycle of your bean. For instance, a utility class with public static methods.

Comment: how can we use it in  external javascript file?

Answer (score 18):

you can inject "grailsApplication" into your source file. here is a sample conf/Bootstrap.groovy

```
class BootStrap {

    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
        println grailsApplication.config
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Another non-deprecated way to get the config is:

```
    ApplicationContext context = ServletContextHolder.servletContext.
        getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT) 
        as ApplicationContext
    ConfigObject config = context.getBean(GrailsApplication).config
```

This works in situations where there is no injected parent available, such as servlet classes or static methods.

Answer (score 4):

You can access grails configuration

1. In Controller

   ```
   class DemoController {
       def grailsApplication

       def demoAction = {
           def obj = grailsApplication.config.propertyInConfig
       }
   }
   ```
2. In services :

   ```
   class DemoService {
       def grailsApplication

       def demoMethod = {
           def obj = grailsApplication.config.propertyInConfig
       }
   }
   ```
3. In taglib :

   ```
   class DemoTaglib {
       def grailsApplication

       static namespace = "cd"

       def demoMethod = {

           def obj = grailsApplication.config.propertyInConfig

           out << obj    
       }
   }
   ```

You can call this method of taglib in view as  `<cd:demoMethod/>`

4. In view :

   ```
    <html>
        <head><title>Demo</title></head>
    <body>
        ${grailsApplication.config.propertyInConfig}
    </body>

    </html>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To access from domain class do:

```
import grails.util.Holders

// more code

static void foo() {
  def configOption = Holders.config.myProperty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import grails.util.Holders

and then you can access by 
def serverUrl = Holders.grailsApplication.config.getProperty('serverUrl')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.