# Grails 2.x service injection in Groovy/src

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'd like to inject my service in Groovy/src class. The normaln dependency injection doesn't work:

```
...
def myService
...
```

I'm able to use this (it works):

```
def appCtx = ApplicationHolder.application.getMainContext()
def myService = appCtx.getBean("myService");
```

but the ApplicationHolder is deprecated. Is there any better solution?

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: How do you use this 'src class'? Where and how you instantiate it?

Comment: I use it inside of other Groovy classes (it is instantiated there). There is a facade groovy class which is used by a service what triggers all that procedures. I don't want to pass used service as parameters in order not to pass so much parameters...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check following Grails FAQ to get access to the application context from sources in src/groovy - http://grails.org/FAQ#Q: How do I get access to the application context from sources in src/groovy?

There is no ApplicationContextHolder class equivalent to ApplicationHolder. To access to a service class called EmailService from a Groovy class in src/groovy, access the Spring bean using:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder as SCH
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes as GA
def ctx = SCH.servletContext.getAttribute(GA.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
def emailService = ctx.emailService
```

Comment: While this will allow you to access methods in a service, it will break the services transactionallity.  Excerpt from [Declarative Transactions](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html#declarativeTransactions): ***Warning: dependency injection is the only way that declarative transactions work. You will not get a transactional service if you use the new operator such as new BookService()***

Comment: @ubiquibacon - yes but "def emailService = ctx.emailService" will be a transactional service.I am sorry but what is the issue with accessing service like this?

Comment: I don't think that qualifies as "dependency injection".  I'll have to do some testing to verify that though.

Comment: @ubiquibacon what is the result of the investigation?

Answer (score 29):

The replacement of ApplicationHolder can be [Holders](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/api/grails/util/Holders.html), you can also use it in static scope:

```
import grails.util.Holders
...

def myService = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean 'myService'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily register new (or override existing) beans by configuring them in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
// src/groovy/com/example/MyClass.groovy
class MyClass {
    def myService
    ...
}

// resources.groovy
beans = {
    myclass(com.example.MyClass) {
        myService = ref('myService')
    }
}
```

Also you can check this question about [How to access Grails configuration in Grails 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7133580/462015)

Comment: Now I see that this doesn't work for me. I cannot bind a service or other properties in resources.groovy like this:
`
import com.path.to.ResidentAtPlace
beans = {
    residentAtPlaceBean(ResidentAtPlace) {
  someProperty = 45
                placeService = ref('placeService')
  grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
    }
}
`

Everything is null in my ResidentAtPlace.groovy Do you see any problem? I'm using Grail 2.0.3

Comment: the same happens to me, any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Yo can do it from the `resources.groovy`:

```
// src/groovy/com/example/MyClass.groovy
class MyClass {
    def myService
    ...
}

// resources.groovy
beans = {
    myclass(com.example.MyClass) {
        myService = ref('myService')
    }
}
```

or just using the autowired anotation:

```
// src/groovy/com/example/MyClass.groovy

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

class MyClass {
    @Autowired 
    def myService
    ...
}

// resources.groovy
beans = {
    myclass(com.example.MyClass) {}
}
```