# Access grailsApplication or Service in groovy class

Tags: grails, service, groovy

I am trying to access `grailsApplication` in groovy class under `src/groovy` but I get a null pointer exception. I also tried to inject a service into the same class and same result. How can I access `grailsApplication` or a service from groovy class? (I am using Grails 1.3.7)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails 2.x service injection in Groovy/src](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640480/grails-2-x-service-injection-in-groovy-src)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dependency injection does not work for groovy classes under `src/groovy`. You can get the access to `grailsApplication` using `ApplicationHolder` like this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder

def grailsApplication = ApplicationHolder.application
```

You can access all services like this:

```
def allServicesArtefacts = grailsApplication.services
```

Comment: For grails 1.3.7 it's a perfect solution. However for grails v2+ you should use solution from Tobias Kraft.

Answer (score 8):

The ApplicationHolder class is deprecated in newer Grails versions (2.0 and above).

There is another way, which is described in one of Burt's blogposts: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1017

Comment: I wonder why they deprecated their Holders and then told us to write our own Holders. If the pattern isn't flawed, why didn't they just fix their implementation?

Comment: Blog post often get deleted - for posterity sakes, please include the actual answer in your post, not just a link!

Answer (score 8):

After Grails 2.0, you should use:

```
 def grailsApplication = Holders.grailsApplication
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have classes that you want to participate with dependency injection from src/groovy or src/java or even 3rd party jars all you have to do is configure them in grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy.

If you had the class mypackage.MyClass in your src/groovy directory that looked like this:

```
package mypackage
class MyClass{
    def grailsApplication
    def myMethod(){
        //uses grailsApplication
    }
}
```

Then by adding the following to grails-app/conf/spring/resoruces.groovy it would get auto-injected:

```
myClass(mypackage.MyClass){bean->
    bean.autowire = "byName"    
}
```

This will work in any version of grails thusfar, and like I said you can even use 3rd party jars - for example I ALWAYS have the following in my resources.groovy:

```
jdbcTemplate(org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate){
    dataSource = ref('dataSource')
}
```

For more comprehensive Spring/Grails documentation see:

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/spring.html