# Accessing 'grailsApplication' from a plugin

Tags: grails, groovy

How do I access "grailsApplication" of the main application from a plugin?

An example situation:
I have a class in a plugin, which needs to get a resource link from the main application, which is usually retrieved via "grailsApplication". How do I do that?

**SOLUTION**
In the plugin class you may simply specify:

```
import grails.util.Holders
Holders.getGrailsApplication()
```

Comment: Have you tried with ApplicationHolder (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374546/access-grailsapplication-or-service-in-groovy-class) ?

Comment: @PawełPiecyk ApplicationHolder is deprecated for grails 2

Comment: In services, you should be able to add `def grailsApplication` and it will be injected into your service.  If your class is a spring bean, then you should be able to inject it inside the `doWithSpring` block of the plugin main groovy file.  If it's neither of these, have you tried using the `Holders` class?

Comment: @tim_yates I have a simple groovy class defined under src/groovy, so I guess I should use the 'Holder' class.

Comment: @TomasP.R. Added as an answer :-)

Answer (score 6):

In services, you should be able to add

```
def grailsApplication
```

and it will be injected into your service.

If your class is a spring bean, then you should be able to inject it inside the

```
def doWithSpring = { ->
    myBean( org.whatever.BeanClass ) {
        grailsApplication = ref( 'grailsApplication' )
    }
}
```

block of the plugin main groovy file.

If it's neither of these, have you tried using the Holders class?

```
def grailsApplication = grails.util.Holders.getGrailsApplication()
```