# Can't access any bean from Quartz Job in Grails

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I am using services in grails and getting and setting data from services in controllers and there is no problem. I know how to use it... But this problem I can't solve, please help me if you know what is going wrong.

There is a QuartzJob, I schedule from service from controller... Data is stored in PostgreSQL. Using last version of all plugins and 2.3.3 Grails. In code below I just want to print nickname, but I can't get service. Tried to get bean, def grailsApplication but with no success.

Grails plugin for Quartz is quartz:1.0-RC11

```
class TestJob implements Job{
    def userService

    void execute(org.quartz.JobExecutionContext t) {         
        try {
            println userService.getUserProfile("farko").username
        } catch (Exception ex){
            println ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

I getting this error

> Error | java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method
>   getUserProfile() on null object Error |   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:77)
>   Error |   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
>   Error |   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>   Error |   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:32)
>   Error |   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
>   Error |   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>   Error |   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>   Error |   at test.TestJob$$EOTRiFAo.execute(TestJob.groovy:27) Error |
>     at test.TestJob$$DOTRiFAo.execute(Unknown Source) Error |   at
>   test.TestJob.execute(TestJob.groovy) Error |  at
>   org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:207) Error |     at
>   org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:560)
>   null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You implement `Job`, but this is rare when using the plugin. Typically you just create a class in `grails-app/jobs` (either by hand or with the `create-job` script) with a name that ends in "Job", and the magic happens. Are you creating the classes in `src/groovy`? You need to use the plugin's conventions to get dependency injection to work.

Comment: DRY is Grails magic... I think there is some short way to solve this. All examples I see there, using services without any problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640480/grails-2-x-service-injection-in-groovy-src this is how to get DI. But I think there is some other solution.