# Accessing grails application config from a quartz job

Tags: grails, dependency-injection, task, quartz-scheduler, jobs

Using grails 2.4.2, quartz:1.0.2, I'm trying to gain access to configuration properties

```
class MyJob {
  def grailsApplication
  int propA
  def MyJob() {
    propA = grailsApplication.config.foo.bar.propAVal
  }
  ...
}
```

grailsApplication, however, doesn't get injected, and is null.

[Can't access any bean from Quartz Job in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225217/cant-access-any-bean-from-quartz-job-in-grails) supposedly relates to this, but I don't really see how the marked answer resolves the OP's question :-/

help?
10x

Comment: Where have you defined you job class? Is it inside grails-app/jobs/ folder?

Comment: @LalitAgarwal: yes. I just used 'grails create-job'

Comment: Ok. It should work, However, can you try this "Holders.config.foo.bar.propAVal" instead of grailsApplication. You would also need to import grails.util.Holders

Comment: @LalitAgarwal: isn't that usage deprecated?

Comment: No its not. ConfigurationHolder is deprecated. Latest API link for Holders: http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/util/Holders.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are accessing `grailsApplication` in constructor, where it's not injected yet.

I recommend to dump useless class property `int propA` and do it this way:

```
  def grailsApplication

  def execute() {
    def propA = grailsApplication.config.foo.bar.propAVal         
    ... 
    //use propA for something
  }
```

Comment: thanks @lukelazarovicless. While the above indeed works (grailsApplication != null) when running the app, grailsApplication is still null when executing the test from an integration test:
    class MyJobSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
       def myJob = new MyJob()
       void "test something"() {
          ...
          myJob.execute()
       }
    }

Comment: @lukelazarovicless: returning to yr original suggestion: I was thinking of the loaded property as belonging to the task class. It would then make sense that accessing this property is done through the class API. So that if, say, the test requires access to that property, it wouldn't directly load it from config, but rather call myJob.propA. I think spring would allow such implementation. How would this be achieved with grails? Is there maybe another hook (other than the ctor) where DI is already complete, but before the object is exposed to users?

Comment: It's out of the scope of this question, probably specific to Spock and not to be solved through comments. Post another question for it.

Comment: @pointyhat This is what you could do in your integration test.  class MyJobSpec extends IntegrationSpec { def grailsApplication void "test something"() { def myJob = new MyJob(); myJob.grailsApplication = grailsApplication;myJob.execute() } }

Answer (score 2):

```
import grails.util.Holders

class MyJob {
    def grailsApplication = Holders.getGrailsApplication()
    int propA
    def MyJob() {
        propA = grailsApplication.config.foo.bar.propAVal
    }
    ...
}
```

In this way you can access 'grailsApplication' from a Quartz job or even from any groovy file inside "/src" folder.

Answer (score 1):

For those using grails 3.x the type of *grailsApplication* now has to be specified explicitly. E.g. instead of:

```
def grailsApplication
```

you need to use:

```
import grails.core.GrailsApplication
...
GrailsApplication grailsApplication
```

If you don't you'll receive the following compilation error:

> The return type of java.lang.Object getGrailsApplication() in *namespace.classnameJob* is incompatible with grails.core.GrailsApplication in
>   grails.plugins.quartz.QuartzJob