# Exposing a configuration property via getter in a quartz job

Tags: grails, dependency-injection, quartz-scheduler

Relating to [Accessing grails application config from a quartz job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992721/accessing-grails-application-config-from-a-quartz-job):

Apparently, DI doesn't happen prior to the creation of a job. I'm guessing this is the same with other grails artefacts (couldn't spot relevant documentation).

In my particular case, I was aiming to load a property from config and expose that property from the job class. In general though, it seems a valid use-case to me, that artefacts will load configuration, and then return those properties via API.

I'm wondering then, how could this be achieved when a class cannot rely on access to grailsApplication.config at construction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as CH

class MyJob {
   def execute() {
      def myConfigVar = CH.flatConfig.get('my.var.setup.in.config.groovy')
      ...
   }
}
```

OR

```
import grails.util.Holders

class MyJob {
   def execute() {
      def myConfigVar = Holders.config.my.var.setup.in.config.groovy
      ...
   }
}
```