# Dynamic autowire in /src/groovy

Tags: spring, grails, autowired

I want to be able to include Services in my Groovy Classes in /src/groovy

I found a solution with :

```
myBean(MyBean) { bean ->        
    bean.autowire = 'byName'
}
```

But I dont want to make this entry in the `resources.groovy` for all Class, so is there a Solution to Autowire all classes in a specific folder?

I'm using grails 2.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be similar to this question: [Grails 2.x service injection in Groovy/src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640480/grails-2-x-service-injection-in-groovy-src)

What we use and is proposed there is to get the service via the application context:

```
import grails.util.Holders
...
def myService = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean 'myService'
```

It's not completely auto-wired, but seems to be the best way to get services into src/groovy.

Edit: also works for Grails 3

Answer (score 1):

You can make a class `com.example.MyClass` in `src/groovy` a Spring bean by adding the following to `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
grails.spring.bean.packages = ['com.example']
```

and annotating the class with `@Component`, e.g.

```
@Component
class MyClass {

    @Value('${conf.apiVersion}')
    String apiVersion

    @Autowired
    SomeService someService
}
```

As shown above, you can dependency-inject the class with the usual Spring annotations such as `@Value` and `@Autowired`. I find this a much more convenient way to register a Spring bean than modifying `resources.groovy`.