# What is the proper way to allow a table name to be changed via configuration in grails/gorm

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I currently have the following code to define my "User" class

```
class User
{
  String username

  static mapping = {
    table ConfigurationHolder.config.console.datasource.table.user.mapping ?: 'user'
  }
}
```

This works fine with grails 1.3.5, but after upgrading to 2.2.1, grails keeps on complaining about `ConfigurationHolder` being deprecated.

So technically it "still" works fine, but what is going to happen once they remove this class. The documentation says "use dependency injection instead". But I cannot use dependency injection since `mapping` is static.

The real question is what is the "right" way to allow renaming a table via configuration?

Thanks
Yan

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access Grails configuration in Grails 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133580/how-to-access-grails-configuration-in-grails-2-0)

Comment: It looks like a duplicate but the real question is more about how to properly rename a table via configuration. It seems that providing your own `NamingStrategy` should do the trick... the catch is how to inject configuration in it...

Comment: I found this old Jira ticket. Maybe it works. http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3680

Comment: Ah, I thought they had covered static-scope in that question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `grails.util.Holders` class to get access to the configuration:

```
class User
{
    String username

    static mapping = {
      table Holders.config.console?.datasource?.table?.user?.mapping ?: 'user'
    }
}
```

Comment: I confirm this solution works. I am just wondering about why grails is deprecating ConfigurationHolder (while specifying to use dependency injection instead) and providing another mean to access it using a different "holder" pattern...

Answer (score 1):

The applicationContext gets passed to the mapping closure as the first parameter.

See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8087 and the source code for details: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.2.x/grails-hibernate/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/cfg/HibernateMappingBuilder.groovy#L61 .

Example usage:

```
class User
{
    String username

    static mapping = { ctx ->
      table ctx.grailsApplication.config.console?.datasource?.table?.user?.mapping ?: 'user'
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work: 2013/03/25 15:11:30.934 ERROR [GrailsContextLoader] Error initializing the application: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [org.linkedin.glu.console.domain.User]:  No such property: grailsApplication for class: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext

Comment: yan, what Grails version are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest one as of this writing (2.2.1)

Answer (score -1):

Try to inject grailsApplication instead. See here: http://digitalbreed.com/2011/deprecation-of-configurationholder-in-grails-2